# addressbook image query

Tags: objective-c, iphone, image, addressbook

Is there any way i can get the path of the image on a particular person on the address book.? Im trying to copy the image on a person and load it into a table view. Im thinking it would be much faster if i just copy the path of the image instead and use the path on the table view.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I would recommend sticking to the ABAddressBook/ABRecord/ABPerson APIs for retrieving the image. Not sure you want to assume you have access to the "path" to the image or even assume that a "path" exists. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess the answer will be theres no available way to get to the path of the image on adress book 
Thanks Eric

Answer (score 0):

Use the image directly. As far as I know, you are able to get de ImageData with the AddressBook API...